# Curl Critical Vulnerability - CVE-2022-32207

Tags: java, gradle, amazon-linux, jib

When I make a new commit, we have a pipeline which runs a security step using Trivy.
Trivy found the following vulnerability:

```
2022-11-09T08:43:14.846Z    INFO    Vulnerability scanning is enabled
2022-11-09T08:43:14.846Z    INFO    Secret scanning is enabled
2022-11-09T08:43:14.846Z    INFO    If your scanning is slow, please try '--security-checks vuln' to disable secret scanning
2022-11-09T08:43:15.018Z    INFO    Detected OS: amazon
2022-11-09T08:43:15.018Z    INFO    Detecting Amazon Linux vulnerabilities...
2022-11-09T08:43:15.022Z    INFO    Number of language-specific files: 1
2022-11-09T08:43:15.022Z    INFO    Detecting jar vulnerabilities...
(amazon 2 (Karoo))
===========================================================================
Total: 2 (CRITICAL: 2)
┌─────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Library │ Vulnerability  │ Severity │ Installed Version  │   Fixed Version    │                   Title                    │
├─────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ curl    │ CVE-2022-32207 │ CRITICAL │ 7.79.1-4.amzn2.0.1 │ 7.79.1-6.amzn2.0.1 │ curl: Unpreserved file permissions         │
│         │                │          │                    │                    │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2022-32207 │
├─────────┤                │          │                    │                    │                                            │
│ libcurl │                │          │                    │                    │                                            │
│         │                │          │                    │                    │                                            │
└─────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I am working on a Java project with Spring and Gradle.
First of all, I tried to see if I could find anything related to curl in the backend. I didn't find anything.
After several investigations and suggestions from colleges, the problem might come from .jib job from gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '3.1.2'
}

// some other dependencies... 

jib {
    from {
        image = 'amazoncorretto:18'
        platforms {
            platform {
                architecture = 'amd64'
                os = 'linux'
            }
        }
    }
    to {
        image = System.env.CI_REGISTRY + '/myproject'
        tags = [System.env.CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA, 'latest']
        auth {
            username = System.env.CI_REGISTRY_USER ?: ''
            password = System.env.CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD ?: ''
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to increment the jib version to:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '3.2.0'
}
```

and using **amazoncorretto:19**

But I still have the same issue. What else could I try? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like a OS vulnerability, i.e. curl would need to be updated. It doesn't seem to be related to your application at all.

Comment: Hi @Thomas. Thanks for the answer. Yes, I also saw this answer on the internet.
I don't really understand this part very well... but I can't figure out where I could upgrade it or if I am the one who has to do this...

Comment: I'm no expert here but I'd assume you'd have to update the AMI you're using for your machine (it's an EC2 instance, isn't it?). As for who should do it: that depends on your team's organization.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Thomas! In the end we ignored the vulnerability :D

Answer (score 0):

I been searching also how to update this vulnerability in aws elasticbeanstalk. been alerting to us and its critical.